# zip two unequal lists into a dictionary. give none if key has no value. ignore value without a key

Tags: python

There are two lists of different lengths. The first contains keys, and the second contains values.
Write a function that creates a dictionary from these keys and values.
If the key did not have enough values, the dictionary should have the value `None`.
Values that did not have enough keys should be ignored.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
dict(zip(a, b))
```

I need this:

```
{'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'4'}
```

for

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2]
dict(zip(a, b))
```

I need this:

```
{'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'None'}
```

Comment: Why `'c':'4'` in the first example?

Comment: @HélitonMartins Good question, I'm assuming it's a typo

Answer (score 8):

`itertools.zip_longest` is what you need:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

dict(zip_longest(a,b) if len(a)>len(b) else zip(a,b))
```

`if` part is to avoid `None` as keys.

Answer (score 8):

Build an iterator from `b` and iterate over `a` getting the next element from `b`, defaulting to `None`, e.g.

```
it = iter(b)
{k: next(it, None) for k in a}
```

Comment: Most elegant solution so far

Answer (score 1):

Dict comprehension way:

```
{key: b[idx] if idx < len(b) else None for idx, key in enumerate(a)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = [1,2,3,4,5]

while len(b) < len(a):
  b.append(None)

c = dict(zip(a,b))
print(c)
```

Comment: what if user inputs 2 lists, instead of defining the lists in the program

Comment: `b.extend([None]*(len(b)-len(a))` to avoid a loop maybe

Answer (score 0):

You can add elements to a list using `+` operator and create a series of new elements using the `*` operator. So I would solve your problem like this:

```py
dict( zip( a, b + [None] * (len(a)-len(b)) ) )
```

Which extends the list `b` in case it is shorter than the list `a` with `None` elements and zips both together.

The output:

```py
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> dict( zip( a, b + [None] * (len(a)-len(b)) ) )
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': None}
>>> b = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> dict( zip( a, b + [None] * (len(a)-len(b)) ) )
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```